# When writing spec files that Python reads, how do I handle versioning those files?

Tags: python

I have a python command line utility that reads a YAML spec file that tells the utility how to behave.  I'd like to version the app's understanding of that file so that when the tool is updated it can still understand old versions of the spec file.  For example, here's a simplified first iteration of the spec file:

```
SchemaVersion: 1.0
Name: Hodor
Eat: apple
```

In this example, the app will output `Hodor ate an Apple.`

Now let's say there is an update to the code which changes how the app interprets the spec file.  Here's version two:

```
SchemaVersion: 2.0
Name: Hodor
Eat: apple
Animal: goat
```

In this example, the app will output `Hodor's goat ate an apple.`

You can see that the `Name` property slightly changed, the `Eat` property didn't change, and a new property was added.
How can I efficiently write my code so that I'm not duplicating things with each version change while still being able to interpret each SchemaVersion as was done with the first version of the app?

Comment: I think standard procedure is to write a set of functions that know how to upgrade Version N to Version N+1.  Then when you read a file that is older than the code expects, you run it through as many version translations as is necessary.  Downgrading is also possible through the same mechanism if you choose to support it.

Answer (score 0):

In your hypothetical scenario, one possibility might be providing a configuration file that tells your app how to interpret the versioned .yaml files.   You could then run your app.py by passing 2 cmd line parameters as follows:

`$ python script.py v1.conf v1.yaml`
`Hodor ate an apple`

`$ python script.py v2.conf v2.yaml`
`Hodor's goat ate an apple`

Contents of v1.yaml:

```
SchemaVersion: 1.0
Name: Hodor
Eat: apple
```

Contents of v1.conf:

```
{
    "version" : "1.0",
    "target_keys": ["Name", "Eat"],
    "output_format" : "%s ate an %s"
}
```

Contents of v2.yaml:

```
SchemaVersion: 2.0
Name: Hodor
Eat: apple
Animal: goat
```

Contents of v2.conf:

```
{
    "version" : "1.0",
    "target_keys": ["Name", "Animal", "Eat"],
    "output_format" : "%s's %s ate an %s"
}
```

Example app.py:

```
import sys
import yaml
import json

def parse_conf(conf_file_path:str) -> dict:
    with open(conf_file_path, 'r') as conf_json:
        return json.load(conf_json)

def parse_yaml(yaml_file_path:str) -> dict:
    with open(yaml_file_path, 'r') as stream:
        return yaml.safe_load(stream)

def lookup_values(yaml_dict:dict, keys:list) -> tuple:
    target_values=[]
    for keyname in keys:
        if keyname in yaml_dict.keys():
            target_values.append(yaml_dict.get(keyname))
        else:
            raise KeyError(f"Key '{keyname}' not found.")
    return tuple(target_values)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # parse conf file and get configuration
    conf_dict=parse_conf(sys.argv[1])
    target_version_keys=conf_dict.get("target_keys")
    target_version_fmt=conf_dict.get("output_format")

    # parse .yaml file and get values
    yaml_dict=parse_yaml(sys.argv[2])
    yaml_values=lookup_values(yaml_dict, target_version_keys)

    # print yaml values using versioned format
    print(target_version_fmt % yaml_values)
```

Comment: This works for my simple example, but I think it falls short of handling more complicated scenarios, such as when those properties are used for more than outputting text.  The code used to interpret each of those properties is going to be too large to place it into a config file.  I do appreciate you answering though!